# Handling Two Login Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I have a login screen for my app that uses a Facebook login and a Twitter login. I want it set up so that if Facebook is used, the users data is saved through Facebook, and if Twitter is used then it uses the twitter information.

Currently I was just trying to do an if statement for the profile images alone, but it doesnt seem to be working the way I want... I am using a UIButton for the Twitter login, and the FBLoginView built in class from the Facebook SDK for the Facebook login. Here is my code snippet for the if statement in my **LoginViewController.m**:

```
- (void)profilePictureChoose:(id)sender{
    if (sender == TWLoginButton){
        theprofilepicture = twitterprofPicture;
    }
    else if(sender == FBLoginButton){
        theprofilepicture = profPicture;
    }
}
```

I have the FB login button linked with the FBLoginButton property and the UIButton for Twitter is liked with the property TWLoginButton. These two properties are saved in my **LoginViewController.h**as such:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *FBLoginButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *TWLoginButton;
```

I also have these two properties for the profile pictures in the same .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic)  UIImage *profPicture;
@property (nonatomic)  UIImage *twitterprofPicture;
```

with **theprofilepicture** as the variable I am using to access the picture from any controller.

I'm not sure how to have the if statement check correctly for which button is clicked. If someone could help me I would appreciate it

Comment: If you set a breakpoint or a NSLog in your profile picture method, what does it reveal about the `sender`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply giving the buttons a tag?

```
 FBLoginButton.tag = 1;
 TWLoginButton.tag = 2;
```

And then modify your profile picture method as follows:

```
- (void)profilePictureChoose:(id)sender{
    if (sender.tag == 1){
        //Facebook button
        theprofilepicture = profPicture;
    }
    else if(sender.tag == 2){
        //Twitter button
        theprofilepicture = twitterprofPicture;
    }
}
```

Try this out and tell me if this helped you, or what the results of it are.

Comment: i tried this and it is still not working.. I think it has to do with the fact that i am not using a UIButton for the FBLoginView. i will try making it a button.

Comment: Oh I completely missed out that you are using images and not buttons! Yep, but theoretically you shouldn't use any of these methods, but use those of the SDK's

Comment: is there just a way to check if the FBLoginView is clicked? As of right now I have it set up fine, but I just need a way to check if the FBLoginView is clicked or not. I tried doing an if statement to see if there is an active FB session but that didnt work for some reason

Comment: just wanted to let you know I got it to work - just did an if statement in the twitter button checking sender == TWLoginButton, and an if statement in the FB method to check for an active session through the property FBLoginButton. Thanks for the help though - you got me going in the right direction!